# tab delimit a file in bash

Tags: bash, file

I have two files. I would like to join them by column and convert them from tab delimited to space delimted. 
What is needed on top of 
    paste fileA fileB

to make that work?

Comment: This is how `paste` works naturally. What did you try, what was the result and did you consult `man paste`? Also, what does `type paste` give?

Comment: might be stupid, I am a long time working on linux command line, first time I see the paste command... I thought op is giving `paste` as an example command. Looking at `man` the command is very limited though. I'm now not surprised I never used it.

Comment: @akostadinov it is limited for a reason (the UNIX philosophy: do only one thing, but do it well), and plays well together with other small commands like `cut`, `cat`, `head`, ...

Comment: @Boldewyn, no, linux ain't UNIX ;) If you look at most GNU tools you'll see how much sugar they have added over the standard POSIX requirements. Because that's useful. Otherwise you end up with a tool nobody uses. Look at the tools you give as examples and you'll see that they have much more tuning knobs.

Answer (score 0):

Through awk,

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR]"\t"$2}' file1 file2
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat m
cat
dog
$ cat r
foo bar
bar foo
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$1; next} {print a[FNR]"\t"$2}' m r
cat bar
dog foo
```

Comment: I didn't know about this solution. It is interesting. It is also good for small datasets as a one-liner. But it appears to me `awk` is not the right tool for this task in general. Buildig an array with content of the whole first file might be memory inefficient and slow. I've not benchmarked it though.

Comment: @akostadinov A way with awk without an array  `awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{printf($0" ");getline <ARGV[2];print}' file file2`

Answer (score 0):

Talking about pure bash, something like this, haven't tested but you should be able to fix any bugs:

```
exec 3<file1
exec 4<file2
while :; do
   read -r -u 3 f1_w || exit
   read -r -u 4 f2_w1 f2_w2 || exit 1
   echo -e "${f1_w}\t${f2_w2}"
done
```